# How can I systemd targets to stop services from other targets?

Tags: systemd

I would like to have several `systemd` targets, call them `TargetA`, `TargetB`, and `TargetC`, that control a set of services, call them `Service01` through `Service7`. The configuration would look something like this:

- `TargetA`

  - `Service1`
  - `Service2`
  - `Service3`
- `TargetB` wants

  - `Service3`
  - `Service4`
  - `Service5`
- `TargetC` wants

  - `Service5`
  - `Service6`
  - `Service7`

Goals:

- Only one target should be allowed to be enabled at a time
- The system administrator should be able to manually start and services at will

My initial setup involved:

- Each target conflicted with the other two targets
- Every service had `StopWhenUnneeded=true` enabled

This met the first requirement. Starting `TargetX` stopped the other two targets. Unfortunately, this setup restricted the sysadmin. If the sysadmin ran `sudo systemctl start ServiceX` the service would launch and then immediately die because it wasn't needed.

My second setup involved:

- Every target conflicted with the other two targets
- Every target also conflicted with the services that it didn't need
- No service has `StopWhenUnneeded=true`

For example:

- `TargetA`

  - Wants

    - `Service1`
    - `Service2`
    - `Service3`
  - Conflicts

    - `Service4`
    - `Service5`
    - `Service6`
    - `Service7`
    - `TargetB`
    - `TargetC`

This doesn't have the desired effect.
If I run:

`sudo systemctl start TargetA.target`

followed by:

`sudo systemctl start TargetB.target`

then `TargetA.target` is stopped (yay!) but `Service1` and `Service2` are still running.

What am I not getting? How can I get the `systemd` behavior that I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Suggested approach:

1. Use `systemctl isolate` to start each of the 3 targets. As documented in `man systemctl`, this is a powerful command: "The isolate command will immediately stop processes that are not enabled in the new unit, possibly including the graphical environment or terminal you are currently using." Structure your target dependencies carefully! Possibly include `multi-user.target` as dependency.
2. Make sure that that the first service the target starts is a special one that checks that the other targets are not active. This defends against an admin accidentally "starting" one of your custom targets instead of "isolating" it.  You use `/bin/systemctl is-active your.target` to quickly check if it returns "active" or not.

Comment: I am attempting to avoid using `systemctl isolate` if I can. If I use `systemctl isolate TargetA|B|C`, then adding an unrelated `TargetZ` down the road because much more difficult, correct?  
Why does activating `TargetB` with `sudo systemctl start TargetB.target` not stop `Service1` and `Service2`? Shouldn't `Conflicts=` directive stop them?

Comment: It depends on how you want to use unrelated targets. You can create and start other targets, and they will run until you stop them or "isolate" a new target that doesn't depend on the unrelated targets. I'm not sure why `Conflicts=` isn't stopping the other services. `man systemd.unit` implies that it would. If you believe you've found a bug, you can file it at https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues